# Sanitize password string in cpp

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have a string ,

userStmt:

```
SELECT * FROM RUN_ON_HIVE(SERVER('10.23.40.23'),USERNAME('user'),PASSWORD('pass'),DBNAME('default'),QUERY('ANALYZE TABLE default.test01 COMPUTE STATISTICS'));
```

I am trying to convert the password clause to "****".

```
String sanitizeduserstmt=userStmt;
  boost::regex pw_re("PASSWORD\\('[^']*'\\)");
  boost::regex_replace(sanitizeduserstmt, pw_re, "PASSWORD('****')");
```

But this is not working . Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?
TIA

Comment: Isn't :

boost::regex_replace(sanitizeduserstmt, pw_re, "PASSWORD('****')");

This line doing it?

Comment: This smells like an extremely bad idea. Just don't log the SQL statements (use prepared statements). Besides, 99.99999% of the time it's a security flaw if you have the password in plaintext anywhere in server software.

Answer (score 1):

The [`boost::regex_replace`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_replace.html) method does not modify the input string inplace, you need to assign the value back to the variable.

In your case, the fix will look like

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string sanitizeduserstmt="SELECT * FROM RUN_ON_HIVE(SERVER('10.23.40.23'),USERNAME('user'),PASSWORD('pass'),DBNAME('default'),QUERY('ANALYZE TABLE default.test01 COMPUTE STATISTICS'));";
    boost::regex pw_re("PASSWORD\\('[^']*'\\)");
    sanitizeduserstmt=boost::regex_replace(sanitizeduserstmt, pw_re, "PASSWORD('****')");
    std::cout << "Result: " << sanitizeduserstmt << "\n";
    // => Result: SELECT * FROM RUN_ON_HIVE(SERVER('10.23.40.23'),USERNAME('user'),PASSWORD('****'),DBNAME('default'),QUERY('ANALYZE TABLE default.test01 COMPUTE STATISTICS'));
}
```

See the [Coliru demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f873fe866d1407f).